# pip3 install not working - No module named 'pip._vendor.pkg_resources'

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, pip

When trying to install a package for Python 3 (in Ubuntu), using `pip3 install packageName` (or `sudo pip3 install packageName`), I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 33, in vendored
    __import__(vendored_name, globals(), locals(), level=0)
ImportError: No module named 'pip._vendor.pkg_resources'
```

I have been reading for days and have tried the following WITHOUT any success:

1. Un-installing and re-installing pip3 using the following code: `sudo apt-get remove python3-pip` followed by `sudo apt-get install python3-pip`. This was suggested in several posts that say that sometimes `pip3` doesn't install properly for Ubuntu. However, it didn't work.
2. Other post suggested it was an `ssl` package problem and that if the `ssl` package doesn't load on Python3, that's the issue. However the following command does not raise any error: `python3 -c "import ssl"`.
3. Some other post suggested the problem was with the `requests` package. I then tried `sudo apt-get remove python3-requests` followed by `sudo apt-get install python3-requests` also to no avail.

Other information you may need:

- `pip3 --version` gives me the same error reported above.
- `dpkg -L python3-pip` gives me the following information:

  ```
  /.
  /usr
  /usr/lib
  /usr/lib/python3
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip-8.1.1.egg-info
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip-8.1.1.egg-info/PKG-INFO
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip-8.1.1.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip-8.1.1.egg-info/not-zip-safe
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip-8.1.1.egg-info/requires.txt
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip-8.1.1.egg-info/entry_points.txt
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip-8.1.1.egg-info/top_level.txt
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/baseparser.py
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__main__.py
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/__init__.py
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_file.py
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_uninstall.py
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/status_codes.py
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/utils
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/utils/setuptools_build.py
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/utils/appdirs.py
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/utils/outdated.py
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/utils/ui.py
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/utils/logging.py
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/utils/encoding.py
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/utils/deprecation.py
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/utils/filesystem.py
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/utils/hashes.py
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/utils/build.py
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/compat
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/compat/dictconfig.py
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/compat/__init__.py
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/compat/ordereddict.py
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/models
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/models/index.py
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/models/__init__.py
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/vcs
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/vcs/bazaar.py
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/vcs/subversion.py
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/vcs/mercurial.py
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/vcs/__init__.py
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/vcs/git.py
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/cmdoptions.py
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/completion.py
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/hash.py
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/uninstall.py
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/__init__.py
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/list.py
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/search.py
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/show.py
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/download.py
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/wheel.py
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/freeze.py
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/help.py
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/operations
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/operations/__init__.py
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/operations/freeze.py
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/locations.py
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/pep425tags.py
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/exceptions.py
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/download.py
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py
  /usr/share
  /usr/share/man
  /usr/share/man/man1
  /usr/share/man/man1/pip3.1.gz
  /usr/share/doc
  /usr/share/doc/python3-pip
  /usr/share/doc/python3-pip/copyright
  /usr/bin
  /usr/bin/pip3
  /usr/share/doc/python3-pip/changelog.Debian.gz
  ```

How can I make `pip3` work?

NOTE: `pip` for Python2 works just fine.

================================================

EDIT:

1. When trying to `import setuptools` in Python3 I get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
        from setuptools.extern.six.moves import filterfalse, map
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/extern/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
        from pkg_resources.extern import VendorImporter
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2927, in <module>
        @_call_aside
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2913, in _call_aside
        f(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2952, in _initialize_master_working_set
        add_activation_listener(lambda dist: dist.activate())
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 956, in subscribe
        callback(dist)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2952, in <lambda>
        add_activation_listener(lambda dist: dist.activate())
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2515, in activate
        declare_namespace(pkg)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2097, in declare_namespace
        _handle_ns(packageName, path_item)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2047, in _handle_ns
        _rebuild_mod_path(path, packageName, module)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2066, in _rebuild_mod_path
        orig_path.sort(key=position_in_sys_path)
    AttributeError: '_NamespacePath' object has no attribute 'sort'
```

2. When running the following command `sed -n '31,37p' < /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py` in the terminal, I get the following:

   ```
   try:
       __import__(vendored_name, globals(), locals(), level=0)
   except ImportError:
       try:
           __import__(modulename, globals(), locals(), level=0)
       except ImportError:
   ```

===========================================

EDIT2:

My `python3 --version` is `Python 3.5.2`.

List of installed packages obtained running the code `ls /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`.

```
apport
apport_python_hook.py
apt
aptdaemon
apt_inst.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
apt_pkg.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
aptsources
AptUrl
apturl-0.5.2.egg-info
beautifulsoup4-4.4.1.egg-info
blinker
blinker-1.3.egg-info
Brlapi-0.6.4.egg-info
brlapi.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
bs4
cairo
_cffi_backend.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
chardet
chardet-2.3.0.egg-info
checkbox_support
checkbox_support-0.22.egg-info
CommandNotFound
command_not_found-0.3.egg-info
cryptography
cryptography-1.2.3.egg-info
cups.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
cupsext.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
curl
cycler-0.9.0.egg-info
cycler.py
dateutil
dbus
_dbus_bindings.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
_dbus_glib_bindings.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
deb822.py
debconf.py
debian
debian_bundle
decorator-4.0.6.egg-info
decorator.py
defer
defer-1.0.6.egg-info
DistUpgrade
easy_install.py
feedparser-5.1.3.egg-info
feedparser.py
feedparser_sgmllib3.py
gi
guacamole
guacamole-0.9.2.egg-info
hpmudext.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
html5lib
html5lib-0.999.egg-info
httplib2
httplib2-0.9.1.egg-info
idna
idna-2.0.egg-info
janitor
jinja2
Jinja2-2.8.egg-info
jwt
LanguageSelector
language_selector-0.1.egg-info
language_support_pkgs.py
louis
louis-2.6.4.egg-info
lsb_release.py
lxml
lxml-3.5.0.egg-info
mako
Mako-1.0.3.egg-info
markupsafe
MarkupSafe-0.23.egg-info
matplotlib
matplotlib-1.5.1.egg-info
matplotlib-1.5.1-nspkg.pth
mpl_toolkits
networkx
networkx-1.11.egg-info
numexpr
numexpr-2.4.3.egg-info
numpy
numpy-1.11.0.egg-info
NvidiaDetector
oauthlib
oauthlib-1.0.3.egg-info
Onboard
onboard-1.2.0.egg-info
orca
padme
padme-1.1.1.egg-info
pandas
pandas-0.17.1.egg-info
pcardext.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
pexpect
pexpect-4.0.1.egg-info
PIL
Pillow-3.1.2.egg-info
pip
pip-8.1.1.egg-info
pkg_resources
plotly
plotly-1.9.5.egg-info
problem_report.py
ptyprocess
ptyprocess-0.5.egg-info
pyasn1
pyasn1-0.1.9.egg-info
pyatspi
__pycache__
pycups-1.9.73.egg-info
pycurl-7.43.0.egg-info
pycurl.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
pygobject-3.20.0.egg-info
pygtkcompat
PyJWT-1.3.0.egg-info
pylab.py
pyparsing-2.0.3.egg-info
pyparsing.py
python_apt-1.1.0.b1_ubuntu0.16.04.1.egg-info
python_dateutil-2.4.2.egg-info
python_debian-0.1.27.egg-info
python_systemd-231.egg-info
pytz
pytz-2014.10.egg-info
pyxdg-0.25.egg-info
PyYAML-3.11.egg-info
Quirks
reportlab
reportlab-3.3.0.egg-info
requests
requests-2.9.1.egg-info
scanext.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
scipy
scipy-0.17.0.egg-info
sessioninstaller
sessioninstaller-0.0.0.egg-info
setuptools
setuptools-20.7.0.egg-info
six-1.10.0.egg-info
six.py
softwareproperties
speechd
speechd_config
systemd
system_service-0.3.egg-info
tables
tables-3.2.2.egg-info
UbuntuDrivers
ubuntu_drivers_common-0.0.0.egg-info
UbuntuSystemService
ufw
ufw-0.35.egg-info
unattended_upgrades-0.1.egg-info
unity_scope_calculator-0.1.egg-info
unity_scope_chromiumbookmarks-0.1.egg-info
unity_scope_colourlovers-0.1.egg-info
unity_scope_devhelp-0.1.egg-info
unity_scope_firefoxbookmarks-0.1.egg-info
unity_scope_gdrive-0.7.egg-info
unity_scope_manpages-0.1.egg-info
unity_scope_openclipart-0.1.egg-info
unity_scope_texdoc-0.1.egg-info
unity_scope_tomboy-0.1.egg-info
unity_scope_virtualbox-0.1.egg-info
unity_scope_yelp-0.1.egg-info
unity_scope_zotero-0.1.egg-info
unohelper.py
uno.py
UpdateManager
urllib3
urllib3-1.13.1.egg-info
usbcreator
usb_creator-0.3.0.egg-info
wheel
wheel-0.29.0.egg-info
xdg
xdiagnose
xdiagnose-3.8.4.1.egg-info
xkit
xkit-0.0.0.egg-info
xlsxwriter
XlsxWriter-0.7.3.egg-info
yaml
_yaml.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

Comment: do you have `python3-setuptools` installed? Also, can you please post the output of `sed -n '31,37p' < /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py`?

Comment: There is clearly a problem with `python3-setuptools`. Please see "EDIT" to my question.

When I run the second command you requested I get:
`    try:
        __import__(vendored_name, globals(), locals(), level=0)
    except ImportError:
        try:
            __import__(modulename, globals(), locals(), level=0)
        except ImportError:`

Comment: Ok, at least we now know there's nothing wrong with `pip` itself. The `_NamespacePath object has no attribute 'sort'` is a known error that plagued me too for a couple of versions. Can you please check what `setuptools` version do you have? Since you can't import `setuptools`, your only option will be to extract the info from file system: `ls /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages | grep setuptools-`.

Comment: The response I get is the following `setuptools` and then a second line that says `setuptools-20.7.0.egg-info`

Comment: Ok, my wild guess is that you are using Python 3.5 and have one or more package installed that uses namespaces - at least this was the setup I had to deal with. Please check your `python3` version: `python3 --version`. As for finding the namespace packages, can you please post the list of packages you have? `ls /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`, I guess.

Comment: Yes, I have `Python 3.5.2`. The list of packages I have installed are added as EDIT2 in my main question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167582/discussion-between-hoefling-and-yamila-omar).

Comment: @YamilaOmar: is your problem already solved now? If yes, then, please write steps of your solution as an answer or, update in your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 105):

This solved it for me:

```
curl -sS https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3
```

try use virtualenv for every specific project not messing with ubuntu subsystem.

Comment: This solved it for me, `pip install --upgrade pip` did not break anything either.

Comment: I get error like this `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'`

Comment: @smftr try with virtualenv.

Comment: If you're using an virtualenv, there is no need to apply `sudo` command so: `curl -sS https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3`

Comment: Worked like a charm

Comment: Once I removed sudo, pip installed correctly on my virtualenv instead of /usr/local/lib/python3.x, thanks to @cpinamtz

Answer (score 42):

I got this error on WSL Ubuntu and the most upvoted solution didn't work for me.

The one that works:

```sh
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python get-pip.py --force-reinstall
```

Comment: This is working also with python virtualenv!

Comment: everytime i crreate a new virtualenv, i nned to do this. How to solve this permanantly? any idea?

Comment: This is the right way to fix a virtual environment

Answer (score 14):

Thanks @s_s.411

I solve this problem with the following commands:

```
curl -sS https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | sudo python3
type pip3
hash -r
pip3
```

Answer (score 7):

I ran into the same problem, on Ubuntu 16.04, using the system python 3.5.2 like you, with pip installed via apt (`sudo apt install python3-pip`) like you, having installed some packages in my home directory with `pip3 install --user` like you (documented in [your chat with hoefling](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167582/discussion-between-hoefling-and-yamila-omar)).

The solution was as follows:

1. Temporarily move away all packages installed with `pip3 install --user`:

```sh
mv ~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages{,_backup}
```

This made `pip3` work again, but of course I wanted to keep the packages. (Note: just moving out `setuptools` was not enough; I am not sure which constellation of packages caused this.)

2. Install an upgraded pip into home directory:

```sh
pip3 install --upgrade --user pip
```

Now the `pip3` command fails (`ImportError: cannot import name 'main'`) because it's still called from the old `/usr/bin/pip3` location in the current shell, as indicated by `type pip3`. To solve this, run:

```sh
hash -r
```

Alternatively, you can always fall back to typing `python3 -m pip` instead of `pip3`.

3. Restore the packages:

```sh
mv ~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages{_backup/*,}
rmdir ~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages_backup
```

4. Now pip was working, but `python3 -m 'import setuptools'` failed with the same exception you saw, `AttributeError: '_NamespacePath' object has no attribute 'sort'`. This could be solved by uninstalling, then reinstalling the `setuptools` package in my home directory (uninstalling alone was not enough):

```sh
pip3 uninstall setuptools
pip3 install --user --upgrade setuptools
```

Finally, `pip3` and the `python3 -c 'import setuptools'` are fine.

Comment: That worked for me, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

> No module named 'pip._vendor.packaging'

The solution for me was to uninstall the system `pipenv` (*installed with the package manager, pacman*), and install `pipenv` from `pip` (which is managed with `pyenv`):

```
pip install pipenv
```

I no longer have issues when running `pipenv install`.

Comment: For me, it worked without uninstalling the system's one.

Answer (score 2):

I tried all fixes on this page and it didn't work, finally I found out my virtualenv was broken and I had to reinstall the virtualenv like so

`deactivate` - deactivate first to be safe

`virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3.8 /path/to/my_virtualenv_python3`

`source /path/to/my_virtualenv_python3/bin/activate` - activate the env egain

Of course replace `/path/to/my_virtualenv_python` with your own path and `python3.8` with a custom version of python if you don't use version 3.8 :)

Also please note this may or may not remove already installed packages, so just reinstall every requirements.txt you need afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

I also have same problem and I solved it by this command.

```
pip uninstall pkg-resources==0.0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I use an old virtualenv version, it is OK.
The old version is 15.1.0.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with Debian 11, my Debian has been updated to major releases several times and it looks like some files were not removed. I had to clean them:

```
# remove pip
sudo apt purge python3-pip

# check that the files don't belong to any package
dpkg -S /usr/share/python-wheels/* /usr/share/python-support/private/*

# remove the files
sudo rm -rfv /usr/share/python-wheels/ /usr/share/python-support/private/

# remove old files since Python is now 3.9
rm -rfv ~/.local/lib/python3.7/

# reinstall pip
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

And `pip` worked again.

Comment: This worked for me 
"rm -rfv ~/.local/lib/python3.7/"