# 'sudo pip3' instead 'pip3' to make pip3 work

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I've a problem with pip3.

My problem was the same as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49478573/pip3-install-not-working-no-module-named-pip-vendor-pkg-resources#51171522) question.

I've tried a couple of solutions posted inside answers and comments and now I think I've (partially) solved.

The fact is that now, when I type the command `pip3`, I get the answer:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name 'main'
```

but if I use `sudo pip3` it seems to work fine.

My pip version (obtained with the command `sudo pip3 --version`) is:

```
pip 18.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip (python 3.5)
```

my version of python is `Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01)`
I'm working on a Linux machine with the following Ubuntu version installed:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

How can I make `pip3` work as before?

Thank you very much for your support

Comment: For a start and to make it actually a valid question, you'd have to extract a [mcve]. Anyhow, I believe PIP can install packages for just one user and using `sudo` switches that user, so that would explain why things fail for another user.

Comment: Try reinstalling pip3. `sudo apt-get purge python3-pip` `sudo apt-get install python3-pip`

Comment: did you run the `pip uninstall …` command you linked to?  those will/should be affecting the Python 2 install (`ls -l $(which pip)` might help you figure out which) and hence shouldn't make any difference to any Python 3 issues

Comment: check 
python3 -m pip install "package"