# Getting an error with pip3 : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._vendor.packaging.__about__'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pip

Whenever I try using `pip3` or anything that contains `pip3`, I get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._vendor.packaging.__about__' pops up.
```

I used it to install `opencv` and used `opencv` for multiple projects yesterday. I have no idea why the error popped up today.

Here is my code:

```
kaushiksankar@Kaushiks-MacBook-Pro ~ % pip3 install opencv-python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/pip3", line 5, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.progress_bars import BAR_TYPES
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/progress_bars.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.logging import get_indentation
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/logging.py", line 17, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.deprecation import DEPRECATION_MSG_PREFIX
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/deprecation.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.packaging.version import parse
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/packaging/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .__about__ import (
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._vendor.packaging.__about__'
```

I am using MacOS.

I cannot find the version of `pip` by any method.
`pip` command cannot be used, hence used `pip3`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pip3 install not working - No module named 'pip.\_vendor.pkg\_resources'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49478573/pip3-install-not-working-no-module-named-pip-vendor-pkg-resources)

Answer (score 3):

Download the `get-pip.py` file and store it in the same directory as python is installed. Or use the following command to download `pip` directly,

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
```

Now execute the downloaded file using the command below:

```
python3 get-pip.py
```

One can easily verify if `pip` has been installed correctly by performing a version check. Just go to the command line and execute the following command:

```
pip3 --version
```

After that, you can install your package:

```
pip3 install package_name
```