# Package 'python3-venv' has no installation candidate

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to install Flask for testing a simple web page.
Unfortunately i got the following message:

```
Command 'virtualenv' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install python3-virtualenv
```

When i do it, i got :

```
Unable to locate package python3-virtualenv
```

I check my python version and I'm on Python 3.10.4

Whent i try  **sudo apt-get update** i got:

```
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Whent i try  **sudo apt-get upgrade** i got:

```
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

And when i try **sudo apt-get install python3-venv** i got :

```
E: Package 'python3-venv' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Newer Python versions come with venv. Just try `python3 -m venv ...`.

Comment: I got the following "The virtual environment was not created successfully because ensurepip is not
available.  On Debian/Ubuntu systems, you need to install the python3-venv
package using the following command", but my problem is that i can't install python3 environment

Comment: You should try to fix the package manager issues first. But that's not a topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo apt install python3-virtualenv` works perfectly fine with me.
Alternatively you can install it using pip

```
pip3 install virtualenv
```

After completion you can check for `which virtualenv` to get the path of the location where it has been installed.

It seems there is an error with your ubuntu, You can use this site and fix it and then install the virtual environment : https://www.tecmint.com/some-index-files-failed-to-download.

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem after upgrading to Ubuntu 20.4 and all my problems stemmed from a very old version of Pip that was solved by this lovely command:

```
curl -sS https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3
```

More information and some alternatives here: [pip3 install not working - No module named 'pip._vendor.pkg_resources'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49478573/pip3-install-not-working-no-module-named-pip-vendor-pkg-resources)